# Test S/KEY support for PCI compliance - CVE-2007-2243

Tags: ssh, pci-dss, centos, cve

In order for our business to be PCI compliant, we need to prove that we are not vulnerable to CVE-2007-2243. This states that:

> OpenSSH 4.6 and earlier, when ChallengeResponseAuthentication is enabled, allows remote attackers to determine the existence of user accounts by attempting to authenticate via S/KEY, which displays a different response if the user account exists,

Now, we run CentOS and according to the RedHat security errata:

> Not vulnerable. The OpenSSH packages as shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux do not contain S/KEY support.

However our acquirer will not accept this as proof. Instead, they want further evidence such as the results of a test etc.

We have ChallengeResponseAuthentication enabled for using two-factor authentication, so we can't just disable this. Is there a simple command line I can run using Putty, for example, provide a bit more detail for them?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Every QSA and ASV I've dealt with has accepted proof of package version and the relevant RHSA showing that that version is not vulnerable to the specific CVE.  I mean, it may not help you, but whoever you're dealing with is being unreasonable.

Comment: Thank you @gowenfawr - I did think they we being so. I'll have to give them a bit of a talking to.

Comment: Ask them for a copy of their preferred test suite and details on how to use that test suite to investigate this vulnerability.  They'll either pony up or be embarrasssed.  Either way, if they're acquiring your company, update your resume.